# Compiling a DLL with gcc for Windows

Tags: c++, gcc, dll

I want to compile a dll from IModel.h with gcc.
The code of IModel.h file:

```
#ifndef IModel_DLL_H
#define IModel_DLL_H


extern "C" 
{
  #ifdef SMPInfrastructureDemoCPP3_DLL_EXPORTS
    #define SMPInfrastructureDemoCPP3_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
    #define SMPInfrastructureDemoCPP3_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif 

  namespace InfrastructureSMPCPP
  { 
    enum ModelStateKind
    {
        MSK_Created,
        MSK_Publication,
        MSK_Configuration,
        MSK_Connected
    };
    class ILogger
    {
        public:
           ILogger ()
           {

           }

};
class ISimulator
{

};
class IPublication
{
};
class IModel
{
    public:
        IModel ();
        SMPInfrastructureDemoCPP3_API void Configure(ILogger Log);
        SMPInfrastructureDemoCPP3_API void Connect(ISimulator simulator);
        SMPInfrastructureDemoCPP3_API ModelStateKind GetState();
        SMPInfrastructureDemoCPP3_API void Publish(IPublication receiver);
         ILogger Log;
};
}
}
#endif
```

to compile this I use gcc with command

```
g++ -c -DSMPInfrastructureDemoCPP3_DLL_EXPORTS IModel.cpp
g++ -shared -o IModel.dll IModel.o -Wl,--out-implib,libexample_dll.a
```

like in this reference http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampledll

after first comman I create a IModel.o file. Ok.

but I can't execute the second command, because this error

```
g++ : unrecognized option '-shared'
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: What version of g++ is that?

Comment: H-i586-cygwin32 (B20)